# How to change icon in polymer by using a on-click function

Tags: polymer

I have iron add  which i use for an accordian style page. Upon toggle of accordion i want to make the icon

icon="add" is a + sign and icon="remove" is a minus sign. The icon will signify if it is expanded or not.

```
<accordion-question>
     <iron-icon icon="add"></iron-icon>
           This is the question
</accordion-question> 

<accordion-answer>
  This is the answer which appears if you toggle
</accordion-answer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that it'd be easier to just to set the attribute in js using `Polymer(dom).setAttribute(attr, value)` rather than mess around with computed bindings.

```
<dom-module is="test-element">
    <template>
        <iron-icon icon="add" on-click="_onClick"></iron-icon>
        <iron-collapse>
            <p>Collapse Content</p>
        </iron-collapse>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "test-element",
    _onClick: function() {
        var button= this.querySelector('iron-icon'),
            collapse = this.querySelector('iron-collapse')
        collapse.toggle()
        if (collapse.opened) {
            Polymer.dom(button).setAttribute('icon', 'remove')
        } else if (!collapse.opened) {
            Polymer.dom(button).setAttribute('icon', 'add')
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

The CSS solution is very appealing too though cause it simplifies the js logic.

Comment: Hi @miyamoto. How do i select the first child? this.querySelector('iron-icon') selects all iron-icons and then it changes state on all of them. How do i choose the nearest child element in polymer?

Comment: Same question as above @miyamoto.  If, for instance, you have multiple collapsible containers on a given page (say in an iron-list template for example), how would one swap the collapse/expand icon for only the one clicked, and not all of the containers?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
<iron-icon icon="{{_getIcon(expanded)}}"></iron-icon>
```

and then

```
onToggle: function () {
  //Maybe this is your click event
  this.expanded = !this.expanded
},
_getIcon: function () {
  if (this.expanded) {
    return 'add';
  }
  return 'remove';
}
```

**Edit:** Improving the _getIcon function, as suggested by @ScottMiles

```
_getIcon: function(expanded) {
  return expanded ? 'add' : 'remove; 
}
```

Comment: The binding should be `icon="{{_getIcon}}`

Comment: The binding should be `icon="{{_getIcon(expanded)}}"` and the JS code should be `_getIcon: function(expanded) { return expanded ? 'add' : 'remove; };`. With those changes, this is a very good answer. :)

Comment: Curly brackets on place for the correct binding :) About the js changes, expanded is a parameter of the function, but it also can be accessed through this.expanded, is there really a benefit on changing the js @Scott Miles? Thanks for the comments

Comment: Making your functions _stateless_ is both performance and maintenance positive. For example, if you change the name of the `expanded` property, you don't have to change your function. Generally, a `_getIcon` function that has no dependency on some object state (`this`) can be shared/used in other contexts, and can be tested independently of any object.

Comment: Very good points, thanks for the comment and clarification :)

Comment: Hi @supita, your solution works like a charm however i have 1 minor issue. All icons change if i click any one of them. How do i code such that it only uses the current? Is there a way in polymer to say the nearest child element?

Comment: Same question as above. If, for instance, you have multiple collapsible containers on a given page (say in an iron-list template for example), how would one swap the collapse/expand icon for only the one clicked, and not all of the containers in the list?

Comment: Yeah would love to know how to use in multiple instances too thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `accordion-question` will have some sort of open/close class or attribute, which should make it as easy as:

```
<style>
  accordion-question:not(.open) iron-icon[icon="add"],
  accordion-question.open iron-icon[icon="remove"] {
    display: inline-flex;
  }

  accordion-question:not(.open) iron-icon[icon="remove"],
  accordion-question.open iron-icon[icon="add"] {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<!-- Shows "add" icon -->
<accordion-question>
  <iron-icon icon="add"></iron-icon>
  <iron-icon icon="remove"></iron-icon>
  This is the question.
</accordion-question>

<!-- Shows "remove" icon -->
<accordion-question class="open">
  <iron-icon icon="add"></iron-icon>
  <iron-icon icon="remove"></iron-icon>
  This is the question.
</accordion-question>
```